# Why is my HTML 5 <CANVAS> animation not displaying properly in Joomla when users leave the front page

Tags: html, animation, canvas, joomla

I build a lovely (!) animation in my Joomla Template using Javascript and the HTML5 tag 
There are 7 transparent clouds on different layers all moving on top of one another while moving across the page. The site name is also part of the  so that clouds can either go behind it or in front of it depending on the layer they are on.

You can see it for yourself there:
http://www.flunki.com

Everything works on the front page.
But as soon as you click on the links (eg. Blog on the left) the animation stops and all I have is one static cloud (sometimes 2) on the left of the screen.
Going back to the front page does not solve this, nor does a reload. A F5 reload cures the problem.

To me it has something to do with caching the page somewhere (Cache in Joomla is turned OFF), but I did not find how to solve the problem.

Can anyone please help?

Here is the code, which is part of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;
var max;
var logopos; 
var background;
var logo;
var width = 1300;
var height = 150;
var cloud1;
var cloud1_x;
var cloud1_y;
var cloud2;
var cloud2_x;
var cloud2_y;
var cloud3;
var cloud3_x;
var cloud3_y;
var cloud4;
var cloud4_x;
var cloud4_y;
var cloud5;
var cloud5_x;
var cloud5_y;
var cloud6;
var cloud6_x;
var cloud6_y;
var cloud7;
var cloud7_x;
var cloud7_y;
var cloud8;
var cloud8_x;
var cloud8_y;
var irun;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("clouds");
    width = window.innerWidth;
irun =+ 1;
    height = canvas.height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // init background 
    background = new Image();
    background.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/backblue.png';

// init logo 
    logo = new Image();
    logo.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/logo.png';


    // init cloud1
    cloud1 = new Image();
    cloud1.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud40.png';
    cloud1.onload = function(){
    cloud1_x = 60;
        cloud1_y = 5;
};

// init cloud3
    cloud3 = new Image();
    cloud3.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud50.png';
    cloud3.onload = function(){
    cloud3_x = max/2;
        cloud3_y = 60;
};
// init cloud5
    cloud5 = new Image();
    cloud5.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud60.png';
    cloud5.onload = function(){
    cloud5_x = max-180;
        cloud5_y = 35;
};
// init cloud7
    cloud7 = new Image();
    cloud7.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud70.png';
    cloud7.onload = function(){
    cloud7_x = 200;
        cloud7_y = 75;
};

// init cloud2
    cloud2 = new Image();
    cloud2.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud60.png';
    cloud2.onload = function(){
    cloud2_x = max-100;
        cloud2_y = 15;
};

// init cloud4
    cloud4 = new Image();
    cloud4.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud50.png';
    cloud4.onload = function(){
    cloud4_x = max-300;
        cloud4_y = -15;
};

// init cloud6
    cloud6 = new Image();
    cloud6.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud70.png';
    cloud6.onload = function(){
    cloud6_x = max-560;
        cloud6_y = 8;
};

// init cloud8
    cloud8 = new Image();
    cloud8.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud40.png';
    cloud8.onload = function(){
    cloud8_x = 0;
        cloud8_y = 38;
};

return setInterval(main_loop, 10);
}

function update(){
max = window.innerWidth;
logopos = (640 + ((window.innerWidth-960)/2));
cloud1_x -= .05;
if (cloud1_x < -128) {
cloud1_x = max;
}
cloud3_x -= .2;
if (cloud3_x < -128) {
cloud3_x = max;
}
cloud5_x -= .15;
if (cloud5_x < -128) {
cloud5_x = max;
}
cloud7_x -= .1;
if (cloud7_x < -128) {
cloud7_x = max;
}
cloud2_x += .1;
if (cloud2_x>max ) {
cloud2_x  = -128;
}
cloud4_x += .05;
if (cloud4_x>max ) {
cloud4_x  = -128;
}
cloud6_x += .15;
if (cloud6_x>max ) {
cloud6_x  = -128;
}
cloud8_x += .2;
if (cloud8_x>max ) {
cloud8_x  = -128;
}
}

function draw() {
ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth-20;
ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);

ctx.drawImage(cloud1, cloud1_x, cloud1_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud2, cloud2_x, cloud2_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud3, cloud3_x, cloud3_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud4, cloud4_x, cloud4_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud5, cloud5_x, cloud5_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud6, cloud6_x, cloud6_y);
ctx.drawImage(logo,logopos,0);
ctx.drawImage(cloud7, cloud7_x, cloud7_y);
// ctx.drawImage(cloud8, cloud8_x, cloud8_y);

}

function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
}

init();



</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In `init()` you are using variable `max` defined in function `update()` which is called right after. You should define `max` before or at the begining of `init()` function. I don't really know why do this even works sometimes.

2) `max = window.innerWidth`

window.innerWidth is available after `<body>` has been parsed and your script is fired before that happens - sometimes (when the cache is clear) it has enough time to load all necessary DOM stuff and calculate window.innerWidth

I see you are using mootools so you can avoid that putting your `init()` function in DOMReady event

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    init();
});
```

3) Nobody answers you because your code is a mess, learn about:

- Arrays
- Loops (for)

Comment: Thank you for the tips and the comments. I understand and corrected point 1 which I added afterwards, and obviously did not think about where putting it. I understand point 2 and was not aware of this. I changed the code to the one that you suggested and now more clouds load, but they stay as static as before. I respectfully disagree with your last point though (except on the placement of the MAX var). I am aware of arrays and loops but since all the clouds start at different places, on different planes with different speeds, I thought that this was the clearest way to fine tune the effects.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out where the problem was, eventually.

First, I removed the code from the template and created a module for it, so that it would load everytime the page would be updated when the user clicked on a menu item.

This did not fix it.

I then went back to the site I used to get started with the animation and used their code in my module and it worked for a while and then stopped. I still don't know why, but I replace the code with that of a simple HTML5 canvas animation and it worked anywhere on the front page. It HAD to be my code then.

I went back though it and found out that I was redrawing the logo using window.innerWidth every time the image was updated (while all the graphics had loaded). It did work the first time the page was loaded, but not the subsequent times as pointed out by [rezoner](http://rezoner), which made me discover all the subtelties of DOMReady (thank you for this).

The updtate code below reflects this, and works like a charm.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>flunkibanner</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div>
        <canvas id="clouds" width="100%" >
         Your browser does not fully support HTML5.<BR>
Maybe it is time to upgrade ?

        </canvas>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;
var max;
var logopos; 
var background;
var logo;
var width = 1300;
var height = 150;
var cloud1;
var cloud1_x;
var cloud1_y;
var cloud2;
var cloud2_x;
var cloud2_y;
var cloud3;
var cloud3_x;
var cloud3_y;
var cloud4;
var cloud4_x;
var cloud4_y;
var cloud5;
var cloud5_x;
var cloud5_y;
var cloud6;
var cloud6_x;
var cloud6_y;
var cloud7;
var cloud7_x;
var cloud7_y;
var cloud8;
var cloud8_x;
var cloud8_y;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("clouds");
    width = window.innerWidth;
    max = window.innerWidth;
    height = canvas.height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth-20;

    // init background 
    background = new Image();
    background.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/backblue.png';

// init logo 
    logo = new Image();
    logo.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/logo.png';
    logopos = (640 + ((window.innerWidth-960)/2));

    // init cloud1
    cloud1 = new Image();
    cloud1.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud40.png';
    cloud1.onload = function(){
    cloud1_x = 60;
        cloud1_y = 5;
};

// init cloud3
    cloud3 = new Image();
    cloud3.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud50.png';
    cloud3.onload = function(){
    cloud3_x = max/2;
        cloud3_y = 60;
};
// init cloud5
    cloud5 = new Image();
    cloud5.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud60.png';
    cloud5.onload = function(){
    cloud5_x = max-180;
        cloud5_y = 35;
};
// init cloud7
    cloud7 = new Image();
    cloud7.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud70.png';
    cloud7.onload = function(){
    cloud7_x = 200;
        cloud7_y = 75;
};

// init cloud2
    cloud2 = new Image();
    cloud2.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud60.png';
    cloud2.onload = function(){
    cloud2_x = max-100;
        cloud2_y = 15;
};

// init cloud4
    cloud4 = new Image();
    cloud4.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud50.png';
    cloud4.onload = function(){
    cloud4_x = max-300;
        cloud4_y = -15;
};

// init cloud6
    cloud6 = new Image();
    cloud6.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud70.png';
    cloud6.onload = function(){
    cloud6_x = max-560;
        cloud6_y = 8;
};

// init cloud8
    cloud8 = new Image();
    cloud8.src = 'http://www.flunki.com/templates/celebs_plazza/images/cloud40.png';
    cloud8.onload = function(){
    cloud8_x = 0;
        cloud8_y = 38;
};

return setInterval(main_loop, 10);
}

function update(){


cloud1_x -= .05;
if (cloud1_x < -128) {
cloud1_x = max;
}
cloud3_x -= .2;
if (cloud3_x < -128) {
cloud3_x = max;
}
cloud5_x -= .15;
if (cloud5_x < -128) {
cloud5_x = max;
}
cloud7_x -= .1;
if (cloud7_x < -128) {
cloud7_x = max;
}
cloud2_x += .1;
if (cloud2_x>max ) {
cloud2_x  = -128;
}
cloud4_x += .05;
if (cloud4_x>max ) {
cloud4_x  = -128;
}
cloud6_x += .15;
if (cloud6_x>max ) {
cloud6_x  = -128;
}
cloud8_x += .2;
if (cloud8_x>max ) {
cloud8_x  = -128;
}
}

function draw() {

ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
ctx.drawImage(cloud1, cloud1_x, cloud1_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud2, cloud2_x, cloud2_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud3, cloud3_x, cloud3_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud4, cloud4_x, cloud4_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud5, cloud5_x, cloud5_y);
ctx.drawImage(cloud6, cloud6_x, cloud6_y);
ctx.drawImage(logo,logopos,0);
ctx.drawImage(cloud7, cloud7_x, cloud7_y);
// ctx.drawImage(cloud8, cloud8_x, cloud8_y);

}

function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
}

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    init();
});
</script>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```